# Unstable nature of Lomuto partition scheme

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

In undergrad Quicksort implementation, Lomuto partitioning scheme is used. We are taught that Quicksort is an unstable partitioning algorithm which is cause of the extra swaps that occurs even when pivot is equal to the element at index j.

```
Lomuto-Partition(A, p, r)
    x = A[r]
    i = p - 1
    for j = p to r - 1
        if A[j] <= x
            i = i + 1
            swap( A[i], A[j] )
    swap( A[i + 1], A[r] )
    return i + 1
```

My question is what would happen if we remove the equality at the condition check ie
instead have

```
Lomuto-Partition(A, p, r)
    x = A[r]
    i = p - 1
    for j = p to r - 1
        if A[j] < x   
            i = i + 1
            swap( A[i], A[j] )
    swap( A[i + 1], A[r] )
    return i + 1
```

This should make it a stable implementation and would reduce the extra swaps needed. Or will it break the algorithm somehow?

Comment: Have you tried *proving* that this partition scheme works and is stable? This is how we know whether a mathematical statement is true or not.

Comment: (`We are taught that Quicksort is an unstable partitioning algorithm` I think Quicksort using Lomuto or Hoare partition an unstable *ordering* algorithm. What happens to *equal keys* smaller than $x$, greater than $x$? What difference does the handling of keys equal to $x$ make?)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks, I just realised that even if we can avoid the extra swaps when elements are equal to the pivot, the last swap (A[i+1], A[r]) can result into the order getting changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @YuvalFilmus pointed out it still won't solve the problem. Even if we can avoid the extra swaps when elements are equal to the pivot, the last swap (A[i+1], A[r]) can result into the order getting changed as the pivot will be swapped into it's correct place.

Answer (score 1):

The partitioning scheme is not stable because of this: it focuses on gathering elements lower than the pivot into a lower partition of the table. But as it is doing so, it kicks elements out of that lower partition to make room. It has nowhere to kick an element, other than by exchanging it with the element which is taking its place, coming from the unprocessed upper partition.  While moving elements into the lower partition preserves their order, the moving of the elements out of the lower partition into the upper partition does not preserve their order. Doing that would require either external storage, or bulk moves within the upper partition (which would cause the partitioning to have $O(n^2)$ worst case behavior).

Example: suppose we have $[6_1, 2, 3, 7, 6_2, 1, 6_3, 5]$. Suppose our pivot value is 5.

We begin with an empty lower partition, and compare $6_1$ to $5$. Then compare $2$ to $5$. That element is lower so we swap it into the lower partition: $[2| 6_1, 3, 7, 6_2, 1, 6_3, 5]$. The $6_1$ is arbitrarily booted out to the position previously occupied by $2$.

Next, we continue: $3$ is lower than $3$, so we add it to the partition. Now we again boot the $6_1$ out: $[2, 3| 6_1, 7, 6_2, 1, 6_3, 5]$.

Now we keep going with $7$. That stays in the upper partition, since it is greater than 5. Likewise $6_2$.

Then we get to the $1$. **Here the problem is seen.** 1 is less than the pivot 5, so we move it into the lower partition. To do that, we have to kick $6_1$ out of the way again.  We move it into the position occupied by 1. And, thus, stability is wrecked, because $6_1$ has jumped over $6_2$:  $[2, 3, 1| 7, 6_2, 6_1, 6_3, 5]$.